# AWS S3 MFA delete from web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As it was already answered in other questions, MFA delete can only be enabled from the cli and not from the web console.

I am not able to find however if an object can be permanently deleted from the web console, after MFA delete was enabled or if it's a cli-only operation as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot delete objects from an MFA-delete-enabled bucket via AWS web console.